# SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have dynamically created iframe that opens HTML url with the same domain.

For e.g. main website is `https://hello.world/` and I insert iframe with `src="https://hello.world/xxx.html"` but sometimes get this error in *Sentry dashboard* (client error logging service)

Comment: not sure how you can get a "cross origin" error if the frame is actually "same origin" - perhaps you're doing something wrong somewhere in some code - also not sure why it would "sometimes" work and "sometimes" fail

Comment: You can check the examples from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/8568965) and may try the workaround as well.